# How can this formula be maximized?

Tags: calculus

It is a formula for the range of a projectile,

```
v = velocity, g = gravity constant
```

The horizontal range of the projectile:

$$d = \frac{v\cos\theta}{g}(v\sin\theta + \sqrt{v^2\sin^2\theta + 2gy_0})$$

Wikipedia's answer for maximizing $\theta$

$$\theta = \arccos\sqrt{\frac{2gy_0 + v^2}{2gy_0 + 2v^2}}$$

I do not understand how Wikipedia maximize the first formula to get the second formula.  What happened to the sin function?  How did they get the second equation from maximizing the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the most pleasant derivative to establish since brute force leads to $$d'(\theta )=\frac{v \cos (\theta ) \left(\frac{v^2 \sin (\theta ) \cos (\theta )}{\sqrt{2 g y_0+v^2
   \sin ^2(\theta )}}+v \cos (\theta )\right)}{g}-\frac{v \sin (\theta )
   \left(\sqrt{2 g y_0+v^2 \sin ^2(\theta )}+v \sin (\theta )\right)}{g} $$ However, since you want the result to be zero, you can simplify it a lot writing first that, at solution, the two terms (before and after the minus sign) must be equal. So, for a derivative equal to zero $$v \cos ^2(\theta ) \left(\frac{v \sin (\theta )}{\sqrt{2 g y_0+v^2 \sin ^2(\theta
   )}}+1\right)=\sin (\theta ) \left(\sqrt{2 g y_0+v^2 \sin ^2(\theta )}+v \sin (\theta )\right)$$ and you recognize that the term inside the left parentheses is very close to the term inside the right parentheses. So, after simplification, the derivative is zero when $$\frac{v \cos ^2(\theta )}{\sqrt{2 g y_0+v^2 \sin ^2(\theta )}}=\sin (\theta )$$ Now, square both sides and replace $\sin ^2(\theta )$ by $(1-\cos ^2(\theta ))$ everywhere. For simplification of the writing, replace $\cos ^2(\theta )$  by $Y$; doing so, after reducing to same denominator and expansion, the above write $$2 Y \left(g y_0+v^2\right)-2 g y_0-v^2=0$$ for which the solution is $$Y=\cos ^2(\theta )=\frac{2 g y_0+v^2}{2 \left(g y_0+v^2\right)}$$ In terms of $\theta$, there are four solutions among which $$\theta =\cos ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2 g y_0+v^2}{2 g y_0+2 v^2}}\right)$$ which is what you found in Wikipedia.

By the way, the maximum value of $d(\theta )$ is given by the nice following formula $$\frac{v \sqrt{2 g y_0+v^2} \left(v \sqrt{\frac{v^2}{g y_0+v^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{v^4}{g
   y_0+v^2}+4 g y_0}\right)}{2 g \sqrt{g y_0+v^2}}$$ I am sure you will enjoy !

Answer (score 1):

Derive the formula $d(\theta)$ to get $d'(\theta)$. Then the maximum is achieved at $d'(\theta)=0$.

In fact, every extreme is achieved at such points. This means you may get more than one solution to $d'(\theta)=0$ and you have to check for each one if the global maximum is there.

Answer (score 1):

It uses differential calculus. When a quantity $d$ is maximized or minimized by adjusting parameter $\theta$, then the derivative $d'(\theta)$ must vanish. Then just solve for $\theta$ in equation
$$d'(\theta)=0$$